# Define your custom class in fxml

Tags: java, javafx

I have a custom class called 'Language', I want to define it in fxml like:

```
<Language fx:value="getBundle">
</Language>
```

Language extends `Object` directly and not any JavaFX component. Obviously it throws the below Exception:

> Unable to coerce com.bl.commons.Language@69435 to class javafx.scene.Node

So how do I do it? What I want is that, most of my modal is in that class and I want to directly call methods of `Language` and set content in fxml itself. If this is not possible then any alternatives?

Comment: I saw a few your questions about, sorry most active [JavaFx forums is Oracle inc. JavaFx members
](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/category.jspa?categoryID=298)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know your class **has to** extend `Node` in some way in order to be added to the list of children of other elements (which is what you are doing when you put it anywhere in FXML), because those children are stored as `ObservableList<Node>`.

Note that this doesn't really mean you have to do anything special, just do:

```
public class Language extends Node // or StackPane or whatever
{
    public Language()
    {
        super();
        // ...carry on...
    }
}
```

If `Language` already extends something else you will want to make that class extend `Node` or rethink your class hierarchy.

Comment: Very interesting post and idea. Very useful for working with class and the java code. But the really good thing is do that into fxml file.